# How to calculate DocVariable In MS Word using dates

Tags: microsoft-word, date

I have DocVariables in MS Word working fine, for example this gives me a date:

```
{ DOCVARIABLE  LEGALDOCEFD  \* MERGEFORMAT }
```

But I need to fill out an expire date, for example:

```
{ DOCVARIABLE  LEGALDOCEFD + 3y \* MERGEFORMAT }
```

Does anyone know if this is possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [my page on formatting date fields](https://addbalance.com/word/datefields1.htm#PageStart) and Paul Edstein's [tutorial on Date Calculations](http://www.msofficeforums.com/word/38719-microsoft-word-date-calculation-tutorial.html).

The following is from Paul Edstein's Date Calculation tutorial. It gives the date three years after the current date.

> {QUOTE {SET Delay 3} {SET yy{={DATE @ yyyy}+Delay}} {SET dd{={DATE @
> d}-({DATE @ d}>28)*({DATE @
> M}=2)*((MOD(yy,4)>0)+(MOD(yy,400)>0)-(MOD(yy,100)>0))}}
> "{dd}-{mm}-{yy}" @ "dddd, d MMMM yyyy"}

The format is shown at the end. To adapt it to your Document variable you would substitute the field { DocVariable LegalDocEFD } for the date field, with the same formatting and set the format to the format you want. For instance, where the field says `{DATE \@ d}` you would use `{ DocVariable LegalDocEFD \ @ d }`. The final picture switch `\@ "dddd, d MMMM yyyy"` gives the format you will see in the document.

I recommend using vba to calcualte a second document variable three years later. A field is going to be complex.

- [Formatting with Field Switches](http://www.gmayor.com/formatting_word_fields.htm) and
- [Change Field Formatting Switch Automatically](http://www.gmayor.com/change_word_field_switch.html)

Comment: say you start with 2024-02-29 and add 3 years. You get 2027-02-29 which isn't a valid date. So it's either "deal with Feb 29 or use one of the other methods you mentioned".

Comment: I revised the answer to take February 29 into account.